# Scraping poorly structured HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a website that I want to scrape using Scrapy that has the HTML structure shown at the bottom of this post (titled **HTML**). I want to be able to extract only the information contained with the first `<td class="small-txt dkgrey-txt rightInfoTD">`, i.e., the one that contains the `<span property ="">` tag. I am currently using the following code snippet to try and grab only that data

```
listings = selector.css("div.whenwhereContent")

        for listing in listings:
            for body in listing.css('td.small-txt.dkgrey-txt.rightInfoTD')
```

However, since there are multiple `<td>` tags with the same class of `td.small-txt.dkgrey-txt.rightInfoTD` (see the admission and tickets data at the bottom of the HTML code), I am getting duplicate results. How can I restrict my `for` loop to only the `<td>` tag with the correct data so as to avoid this problem?

**HTML**

```
<div class="whenwhereContent">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">    
        <tr>
            <td class="small-txt medgrey-txt leftLabelTD">
                WHERE
            </td>
            <td class="small-txt dkgrey-txt rightInfoTD">
                <span property="v:name">
                    Sound Academy
                </span>
                <span property="v:street-address">
                11 Polson
                </span>
                <span property="v:locality">
                    Toronto
                </span> 
                <span property="v:postal-code">
                M5A 1A4
                </span>
                <span property="v:tel" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    416-461-3625
                </span> 
                info@sound-academy.com 
                <a href="http://sound-academy.com" style="font-weight:900">
                    <span property="v:url">
                        sound-academy.com
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td><
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="small-txt medgrey-txt leftLabelTD">
                ADMISSION
            </td> 
            <td class="small-txt dkgrey-txt rightInfoTD">
                $39.50-$55
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="small-txt medgrey-txt leftLabelTD">
                TICKETS AT
            </td> 
            <td class="small-txt dkgrey-txt rightInfoTD">
                LN, RT, SS
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="small-txt medgrey-txt leftLabelTD">
                WHEN
            </td>                                   
            <td class="rightInfoTD">
                <div class="small-txt dkgrey-txt">
                    <span property="v:datestart" content="2014-03-24">
                        Mar&nbsp;24
                    </span>  
                    <span property="v:datestart" content="2014-03-25">
                        Mar&nbsp;25
                    </span> 
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict to the `td` in the first `tr` you can use [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo):

```
listing.css('tr:nth-child(1) td.small-txt.dkgrey-txt.rightInfoTD')
```

or equivalently:

```
listing.css('tr:first-child td.small-txt.dkgrey-txt.rightInfoTD')
```

CSS selectors can be quite helpful and are usually easier to maintain. But in some cases, XPath may be the only way to achieve some specific selection. In your case, selecting a `td` that contains `<span property="v:name">` you can do something like

```
listing.xpath('.//td[ span[ @property="v:name" ] ]')
```

Comment: I appreciate the update re: XPath. Also very helpful.